# Keep NotifyIcon balloon tip on screen

Tags: c#, notifications, balloon-tip

Is it possible to set, that the balloon tip do not fade away unless I close it?

This is my code:

```
PazIcon.BalloonTipText = "It has happened!";
PazIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Information";
PazIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
PazIcon.Visible = true;
PazIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the intention of a [notification tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx):

> Minimum and maximum timeout values are enforced by the operating system and are typically 10 and 30 seconds, respectively, however this can vary depending on the operating system. Timeout values that are too large or too small are adjusted to the appropriate minimum or maximum value. In addition, if the user does not appear to be using the computer (no keyboard or mouse events are occurring) then the system does not count this time towards the timeout.

If you need a tooltip to remain on the screen, you would have to popup your own form in the corner.